# Is there a snippet to write a property faster than the current implementation using 'propfull' in C# in VS 2013?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, properties, code-snippets

I am using so many property while I am writing code and it takes so much time to write property with a private and public variable.

**I want property like this:**

```
private int value;

public int Value
{
    get
    {
        return value;
    }
    set
    {
        this.value = value;
    }
}
```

Currently, I am using the snippet `propfull` but it doesn't meet my wants. Because when used it, the property name is same with the private variable name like below and I have to do some changes in the property.

**`Propfull` results like this:**

```
private int value;

public int value
{
    get
    {
        return value;
    }
    set
    {
        this.value = value;
    }
}
```

So, I am searching a snippet that just need you to write the private variable name and can change correctly all value names itself (The correct state is that the public value name is same with the private value name, only change the first character to uppercase). Is there such a snippet to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

You can just modify the snippet to fit your needs, I've done this in the past to the default new class file to remove extraneous usings.

> To modify an existing IntelliSense Code Snippet
>
> - Use the Code Snippets Manager to locate the snippet that you want to modify.
> - Copy the path of the code snippet to the clipboard and click OK.
> - On the File menu, click Open, and click File.
> - Paste the snippet path into the File location box and click OK.
> - Modify the snippet.
> - On the File menu, click Save. You must have write access to the file to save it.

The above is taken from [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k5941d54(v=vs.100).aspx).

For reference here is the propfull snippet that comes with VS 2015 it is slightly different than the one from VS 2013

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<CodeSnippets  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/2005/CodeSnippet">
    <CodeSnippet Format="1.0.0">
        <Header>
            <Title>propfull</Title>
            <Shortcut>propfull</Shortcut>
            <Description>Code snippet for property and backing field</Description>
            <Author>Microsoft Corporation</Author>
            <SnippetTypes>
                <SnippetType>Expansion</SnippetType>
            </SnippetTypes>
        </Header>
        <Snippet>
            <Declarations>
                <Literal>
                    <ID>type</ID>
                    <ToolTip>Property type</ToolTip>
                    <Default>int</Default>
                </Literal>
                <Literal>
                    <ID>property</ID>
                    <ToolTip>Property name</ToolTip>
                    <Default>MyProperty</Default>
                </Literal>
                <Literal>
                    <ID>field</ID>
                    <ToolTip>The variable backing this property</ToolTip>
                    <Default>myVar</Default>
                </Literal>
            </Declarations>
            <Code Language="csharp"><![CDATA[private $type$ $field$;
    public $type$ $property$
    {
        get { return $field$;}
        set { $field$ = value;}
    }
    $end$]]>
            </Code>
        </Snippet>
    </CodeSnippet>
</CodeSnippets>
```

Comment: I tried it before, but I couldn't change the first character to the uppercase and I couldn't find any solution for this trick in google.

Comment: I'm using vs 2015 and noticed that the propfull is slightly different I will post it for you tomorrow. On a side note If you happen to use resharper you can use their live templates instead.

Comment: I have used `ReSharper` before but it contains so much feature that most of them are useless and unnecessary for me and it is too big to use only for a template. Any small extension for the same job?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of but their newest version is quite a bit more performant than it used to be.  And admittedly there are lots of features that I don't use but that is mainly because I've either forgotten them or haven't discovered them yet. :)